Computer restarts when playing any sound from speakers
I have recently installed a new 5.1 sound card that uses Cmedia 8738 sound drivers.
I was originally using Windows 10 but each time I played any sound through the speakers my computer would restart itself when I have the drivers installed.
I switched to Kubuntu 22.04 as I know that the Cmedia drivers are well supported within the kernal.
The sound card is seen by the OS without issue, even displaying the 8738  driver. Again though, if I switch from stereo to 4 speaker from the drop down or if I play a 5.1 test YouTube video my computer restarts.
My computer specs are as follows:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5500
Memory: 32 GB DDR4
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 580 2048SP
Motherboard: MSI B450M PRO-VDH Max
Since a similar issue occurred on Windows I have ruled out the OS and software. Potentially a compatibility issue with the Motherboard or the BIOS version?
I have also installed pulseaudio which has not solved the problem
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Can you try it with a different motherboard? And just to confirm, does onboard audio work correctly?

I installed the sound card onto an old MSI motherboard and I did not experience the same issue. So, there must be a a compatibility issue with my current board. Thanks a lot for the comment, I will look into getting a new motherboard with built in 5.1 support. Thanks again.
